# Редирект без get-параметров

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

Необходимо сделать редирект без get-параметров.В файле .htacees имеется код:

```
    RewriteEngine On


        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
        RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://formaspravki.com? [R=301,L]

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.formaspravki\.com
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://formaspravki.com/$1? [R=permanent,L]

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.forma-spravki\.com
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://formaspravki.com/$1? [R=permanent,L]

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forma-spravki\.com
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://formaspravki.com/$1? [R=permanent,L]

        DefaultLanguage ru
        AddDefaultCharset windows-1251
        #php_value default_charset "cp1251"

        # Редиректы
        RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)(/?)$ index.php?cstart=$1? [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$index.php?do=cat&category=$1&cstart=$2[L]
        RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ index.php?do=cat&category=$1 [L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/rss.xml$ engine/rss.php?do=cat&category=$1 [L]
        RewriteRule ^page,([0-9]+),([^\/]+).html$ index.php?do=static&page=$2&news_page=$1 [L]
        RewriteRule ^print:([^\/]+).html$ engine/print.php?do=static&page=$1 [L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^([^\/]+).html$ index.php?do=static&page=$1 [L]

        Redirect 301 /spravka_rabotodatelyu_o_beremennosti.html http://formaspravki.com/spravka-o-beremennosti.html
        Redirect 301 /spravka_o_beremennosti_obrazec.html http://formaspravki.com/spravka-o-beremennosti.html
```

На страницах после редиректа светят параметры ?do=static&page='название страницы',удаляй их или нет.
При добавлении следующего кода ссылки стали верными, но контент не прогружается пишет :"На этой странице обнаружена циклическая переадресация":

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !="^do=static$"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://formaspravki.com/$1? [L]
```

Добавление знаков вопроса в конец директив и удаление query-string не помогает.Есть у кого варианты решения?

Comment: Замените везде [^/] на [^\/] - не помогло(

Comment: Насколько я понял это обеспечивает строка `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://formaspravki.com? [R=301,L]`.Тем не менее параметры пропадают только при добавлении кода с %{QUERY_STRING} который я привел в вопросе.Так что судя по всему дело именно в .htaccess

Comment: Добавил полное содержание файла

Comment: Можно ли как-то обойти циклическую переадресацию?Ссылка становится верной.Возможно у меня ошибка в выражении?

Comment: Админы,верните ответы!

Comment: это не админы, это Visman сам удалил свой ответ. Попросить его чтобы вернул?

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему! `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^do=static&page=old-name$"
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)$ new-link$1? [R=permanent,L]`